# Sidebar with slide-out feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a sidebar that has a slide-out feature. When you click on it, it shows more items. I made it with JS and HTML but I think the code can be done more efficiently. How can I clean the code up?

```
$('.slide-out').on('click', function() {
    let data = 'slideout-item';
    if($(this).data(data)) {
        let item = $('.slide-out-' + $(this).data(data));
        if(item.hasClass('slideout-active')) {
            item.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
            item.removeClass('slideout-active');
            $('.slide-out-overlay').fadeOut()
        } else {
            item.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
            item.addClass('slideout-active');
            $('.slide-out-overlay').fadeIn()
        }
    }
});

$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    let items = ['content', 'system', 'account', 'other'];
    let item = '.slide-out-';
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if($(item + items[i]).hasClass('slideout-active')) {
            $(item + items[i]).hide("slide", { direction: "left"}, 250);
            $(item + items[i]).removeClass('slideout-active');
            $('.slide-out-overlay').fadeOut();
        }
    }
});

<ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="sidebar-item title">{{ __('Information') }}</li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="sidebar-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('home') ? 'sidebar-active' : '' }}">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item title">{{ __('System') }}</li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link slide-out" data-slideout-item="content">Content<i class="far fa-chevron-right" style="position:absolute; right: 0;"></i></a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link slide-out" data-slideout-item="system">System<i class="far fa-chevron-right" style="position:absolute; right: 0;"></i></a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link slide-out" data-slideout-item="account">Account<i class="far fa-chevron-right" style="position:absolute; right: 0;"></i></a></li>
        <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link slide-out" data-slideout-item="other">Other<i class="far fa-chevron-right" style="position:absolute; right: 0;"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="slide-out-block shadow slide-out-content" id="slide-out">
    <nav class="sidebar-slideout">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="sidebar-item title">{{ __('Content') }}</li>
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="{{ route('pages') }}" class="sidebar-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('pages') ? 'sidebar-active' : '' }}">{{ __('Pages') }}</a></li>
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="{{ route('blocks') }}" class="sidebar-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('blocks') ? 'sidebar-active' : '' }}">{{ __('Blocks') }}</a></li>
            <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="{{ route('layouts') }}" class="sidebar-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('layouts') ? 'sidebar-active' : '' }}">{{ __('Layouts') }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while since I worked with `jQuery` so I may not get specific API's correct.

1. You are repeating `("slide", { direction: "left"}, 250)`, if you ever changed one of the properties I would assume you'd want them to be consistent with each other. You can set an array then destructure that when calling `show` or `hide`. You can also apply this theory to your strings such as `slide-out-overlay` and `slideout-active` for example, if you find yourself typing the same strings out, generally you want to put them in a variable (ideally a `const`)

```
// OLD
$('.slide-out').on('click', function() {
    ...
    item.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
    ...
});

$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    ...
    item.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
});

// NEW
const toggleArguments ["slide", { direction: "left" }, 250]
$('.slide-out').on('click', function() {
    ...
    item.hide(...toggleArguments);
    ...
});

$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    ...
    item.hide(...toggleArguments);
});
```

2. It's common practice to use guard clauses, to reduce nesting. Closely related is early return's too, you should never really need the `else` statement.

```
// OLD
$('.slide-out').on('click', function() {
    let data = 'slideout-item';
    if($(this).data(data)) {
        let item = $('.slide-out-' + $(this).data(data));
        if (something) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
});

// NEW
$('.slide-out').on('click', function() {
    let data = 'slideout-item';
    if (!$(this).data(data)) {
        return;
    }

    if (item.hasClass('slideout-active') {
        ...
        return;
    }

    // do code for !item.hasClass('slideout-active')
});
```

3. It is sometimes clearer to put a `$` in front of variables that are `jQuery` objects

```
// OLD
let item = $('.slide-out-' + $(this).data(data));

// NEW
let $item = $('.slide-out-' + $(this).data(data));
```

4. In your `.slide-out-overlay` click function, you are finding `.slide-out-overlay` again within the function block, when you already have the element in `this`

```
// OLD
$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    ...
    $('.slide-out-overlay')...
});

// NEW
$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function() {
    $(this)...
});
```

5. In your `.slide-out-overlay` click function you are looping over any array of strings and then checking if the relevant element has class `slideout-active`. Could you not just look for elements that have `slideout-active`?

```
// OLD
$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    let items = ['content', 'system', 'account', 'other'];
    let item = '.slide-out-';
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if($(item + items[i]).hasClass('slideout-active')) {
            ...
});

// NEW
$('.slide-out-overlay').on('click', function () {
    const $items = $('.slideout-active');
    $items.hide("slide", { direction: "left"}, 250); // .hide works on an array of elements, as do most jQuery methods
    ...
});
```

6. You seem to be using `let` where you can use `const`. Only ever use `let` if you are modifying the value later on. Otherwise use `const`
7. String interpolation is also an option to concatante your strings. Although with jQuery may look a little confusing

```
// OLD
let item = $('.slide-out-' + $(this).data(data));

// NEW
let item = $(`.slide-out-${$(this).data(data)}`);
```

I would also challenge you to write this without jQuery and use vanilla javascript and CSS transitions on the classes.

Hopefully that helps!